# Estou tentando listar dados do meu banco,mais precisamente da coluna cpf,mais so consigo trazer um dado

Tags: java, mysql

```
List < VarUnica > list = new ArrayList < VarUnica > ();
    String queri = "select cpf from funcionario";
    VarUnica alt = new VarUnica();
    Statement ttpa;
    try {
        ttpa = Conexao.getConexao().createStatement();
        ResultSet tr = ttpa.executeQuery(queri);
        while (tr.next()) {
            alt.setRp(tr.getString("cpf"));

            list.add(alt);
        }
        for (VarUnica c: list) {
            System.out.println(alt.getRp());

        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InserindoDados.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguém pode me onde estou errando,obrigado.

Comment: Alguém pode me dizer onde estou errando,obrigado.

Comment: Tenta colocar isso: `VarUnica alt = new VarUnica();` dentro do While

Comment: vc não precisa do outros setters em  `alt`? se tem `alt.setRp()` deve ter outro como `alt.setNome()`, `alt.setAlgumaOutraCoisa()` ?

Comment: Consegue posta o codigo onde você abre a conexão com o banco?

Comment: Primeiro de tudo tente eliminar as possibilidades de erros, antes do while veja quantos elementos tem o result set. Também acho que deve ser porque você não está instanciando o objeto dentro do while, assim ele não está criando uma nova instância.

Comment: Na coluna cpf eu tenho 3 registros.

Comment: @GleistonJosedeSantana Testou o que eu falei?

Comment: testei mais deu erro...

Comment: @GleistonJosedeSantana Qual erro?

Comment: Olha no banco tem 3 registros,o resultado no console é 3 registros,mais esses 3 registros é o mesmo,ou seja estão vindo 3 dados iguais,o que eu quero é que venha os 3 diferentes,entendeu.

Comment: @GleistonJosedeSantana Eu entendi, mas você não formulou bem sua pergunta e acho que não está fazendo certo o que eu falei.

Comment: desculpas,poderia me orientar de uma maneira mais clara.

Comment: Gente a ideia de estanciar deu certo,mais precisei colocar no Sys...(c.getRp);.....Obrigado pelo força galera.

Comment: Você estava alterando apenas a referência do objeto a cada iteração. Por isso só conseguia pegar um objeto, o último. Deve-se instanciar um novo objeto a cada iteração.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa instanciar seu objeto dentro do `While` pois dessa forma você irá criar um novo objeto antes de coloca-lo em uma lista. No seu `FOR` você precisa usar o variável de instância que foi criada no for.

```
for (VarUnica c: list) {
   //c represnta o objeto dentro dessa iteração
   System.out.println(c.getRp());
}
```

O Código completo ficaria dessa forma:

```
List <VarUnica> list = new ArrayList <VarUnica> ();
    String queri = "select cpf from funcionario";
    Statement ttpa;
    try {
        ttpa = Conexao.getConexao().createStatement();
        ResultSet tr = ttpa.executeQuery(queri);
        while (tr.next()) {
            //Criando um novo objeto a cada iteração
            VarUnica alt = new VarUnica();
            alt.setRp(tr.getString("cpf"));
            list.add(alt);
        }
        for (VarUnica c: list) {
            System.out.println(c.getRp());
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InserindoDados.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```